# SQLAlchemy context manager value not being returned

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following code in an attempt to not have to have duplicated session management code. The problem is that `session.add` in the `add_model` function is giving me `None` because the `flush` method needs to be called so that `session.add` will give me the new object with it's id. I can't figure out how to get around this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

def add_model(model):
    with session_scope as session:
        return db.session.add(model)
```

Comment: What do you want `add_model()` to return?

Comment: Hi @jwodder. I want it to return the model object that was added, with the id present. I can see that a new row is indeed getting persisted to my db when I call this function fwiw.

Comment: [`session.add`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add) is giving you `None` because it does not return anything (but in that case functions return `None` implicitly in Python). It does not give you the new object with its id.

Comment: Yes thank you. My mental model of how `session.add` works was not quite correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model` doesn't get an ID until after a flush or commit, but since you're already committing inside your function, you can just return the object after the commit, at which point SQLAlchemy will have updated the object with a primary key:

```
def add_model(model):
    with session_scope as session:
        db.session.add(model)
    return model
```

Comment: Ah of course, I should have been returning the model object that gets mutated. Thanks!

Comment: If `model` was a transient object, after calling `add_model` attempts to access attributes of `model` will result in `DetachedInstanceError` (unless expire on commit is disabled).

Comment: Yes great point. The way I have been getting around this is to to a deepcopy of the object so that it can be accessed elsewhere, which I'm not too happy with. I am curious how other people get around this. I wasn't aware of `expire_on_commit`, guess that's the best way?

Comment: You could `session.merge()` to a new session, which consults the database and returns the merged instance, but having a single function use a session like this seems a bit odd to begin with. The session scope should most probably be external to the function.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the way I am doing this is kinda suboptimal. Could you please point me to some code to demonstrate how the session scope could be external to the function?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it is a good read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182113/discussion-between-andrew-winterbotham-and-ilja-everila).